# Primefaces <p:ajax update="@all" /> doesn't work

Tags: spring, jsf-2, primefaces, liferay-6, mojarra

I've got a problem with using p:ajax update atribute element. When I use in my code `<p:ajax update="@all" />` then I am getting `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException`. When I use `<f:ajax render="@all" />` I don't get any. I though that thouse tags are nearly same. Can anyone explain whats happening?

I am using mojjara implementation, primefaces 3.5 and Liferay jsf portlet bridge.

Example of stacktrace:

> Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/views/personForm.xhtml @95,99 value="#{personManagementBean.item.contact.phoneNumber}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
>       at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.findImplicitConverter(InputRenderer.java:170)
>       at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.findConverter(InputRenderer.java:190)
>       at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getConvertedValue(InputRenderer.java:196)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)

Two buttons:

```
<p:commandButton value="not working" action="#{enrollmentManagementBean.cancelEnrollment}">
    <p:ajax update="@all" />
</p:commandButton>
<h:commandButton value="working" action="#{enrollmentManagementBean.cancelEnrollment}">
    <f:ajax render="@all" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Did you try <p:commandButton update="@all" .../> ?

Comment: `Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null` suggests that `item` or `contact` is `null`. Have you verified this?

Comment: RongNK: Initially I didn't try <p:commandButton update="@all" .../> but it works actualy. I am even more confused about what is happening here. Thought that update attribute inside commandButton has same functionality as the one in p:ajax tag.

BalusC: It is null (I am not initializing it anywhere) but the code works as long as I don't use <p:ajax update.../>. I though that EL is "null-safe" (if anything like that even exists :D).

Answer (score 9):

OptimusPrime (main developer of Primefaces) states that `update="@all"` is a bad idea and primefaces does not implement it by design [link to forum post](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6956).

What I do in order to get around the problem is rely on page refresh from javascript. Just put it in the `oncomplete` attribute of the button.

```
oncomplete="window.location.replace(window.location.href);"
```

I believe this should solve your problem if you still have it, or be here for future reference.