# p:selectOneMenu failed after update itself

Tags: primefaces, selectonemenu

I`m using primafaces 6.1 and selectonemenu component to change language of website. Everything works fine, apart from that, after I change the language and update selectOneMenu component responsible for language change with new translations of languages to choose, component stops working. New translations of languages appears just below last clicked old translation, and click action is not working anymore. When I'm not updating component responsible for language change with new item labels everything works well.
bellow is my jsf code:

```
<h:form>
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{worker.locale}" id="selectLanguage"
                    valueChangeListener="#{worker.onLocaleChange}">
                        <p:ajax event="change" update="@all" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{worker.locales}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </h:form>
```

And backing bean:

```
    public void onLocaleChange(ValueChangeEvent e) {
    msg = ResourceBundle.getBundle("myApplication", LocaleUtils.toLocale(e.getNewValue().toString()));
    locales  = new HashMap<String, String>();
    locales.put(msg.getString("en_US"), "en_US");
    locales.put(msg.getString("de_DE"), "de_DE");

}
```

I have been trying with  listener="#{worker.onLocaleChange}"  in p:ajax as well, but this doesn't work neither.

Build info

> ```
>     INFO:
> ```
>
> ICEsoft Technologies Inc.
>   ICEfaces 3.3.0
>   Build number: x
>   Build date: 130419
>   Revision: 34423

and pom configuration:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>icefaces-ace</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>icefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icepush</groupId>
        <artifactId>icepush</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>icefaces-compat</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
       <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
       <version>6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You tag it PrimeFaces, show a `p:selectOneMenu` but the build info is about IceFaces...

Comment: What JSF version and impl do you use? And tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352372/primefaces-pajax-update-all-doesnt-work ?

Comment: JSF VERSION: 2.1.21

Comment: There were two questions in my previous comment... The implementation?

Comment: I have added pom configuration

Comment: Did you try a [mcve] in a very clean new project with just PrimeFaces? And what a bout the link I possted?

Comment: About a link, this code: oncomplete="window.location.replace(window.location.href);" after I put in p:ajax tag works well, but I don't think is a good idea to add another request after ajax response. We use ajax to avoid all page refresh and full data flow, and this code requires one more request with all page refresh.

Comment: if you don't update anything in the ajax response (so `update="@none"`, but also use `process="@this"` and `partialSubmit="true"`), the ajax call is very lightweight and the next request does all the work... And how often does this happen? Rarely I'd think... I don't see the problem in using the other solution then.

Comment: Kukeltje thank you for your assistance and I have finally found the source of the problem. The problem is configuration of icefaces together with primafaces in pom.xml file. Even, if I'm not using icefaces on the same page together with primafaces icefaces are breaking up for some reason the functionality of primafaces

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some error. You can try to Switch on debug messages. 
I guess using javax.faces.model.SelectItem for the entries instead von HashMap will solve the problem.

Comment: Why do you think the ancient selectItem will solve the issue? The HashMap initially works...